# How to publish Chrome App into For Your Desktop collection

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I created Chrome App.

But it now appears in **For Your Desktop** collection in Chrome Web Store.
Is there any special activities I should do for that?

Also, what is the difference between **For Your Desktop** and **Offline Apps** categories?

Answer (score 1):

That collection is curated. If your Chrome App is successful, the curators will consider including it in the collection.

Comment: Any special requirements for this? And is there any submit form?

Comment: No. I have to enter 15 characters to submit this comment.

Comment: No for requirements or for submit form?